# Getting "Vim: Caught deadly signal ILL" when trying to do basic git operations

Tags: git, vim, vi

When I run

```
$git pull
```

I get:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal ILL
Vim: Finished.
error: vi died of signal 4
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

When I run

```
$git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

I get:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal ILL
Vim: Finished.
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/git/1.8.0-boxen1/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: line  212: 40705 Illegal instruction: 4  vi "$@"
 Could not execute editor
```

I used to get errors when I ran:

```
$vi
```

But was able to get around them by adding these lines to my .bashrc:

```
alias vi='/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/vim/7.3.843/bin/vim'
alias vim='/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/vim/7.3.843/bin/vim'
```

This is killing my workflow, any ideas on fixing it?

Comment: A bunch of plugins can be the cause of that issue. In the last three years I've seen supertab mentioned, pathogen or even just having a `~/.vimrc`. The solution has always been to use the full path in `git config`. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092432/could-not-execute-editor?rq=1).

Comment: I don't think git sees the bash alias. So git will execute whatever version of vi that comes first in your path. And it looks like you are running Mac OSX. Which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved the issue. At least, partially.

My git config editor, like romainl suggested, needed to be edited. For some reason the instance of vi that it was pointing to '/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/vim/7.3.843/bin/vi' which was corrupted in someway. By adding this line to my .gitconfig:

```
editor = /opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/vim
```

The problems went away.

Comment: it's likely not corrupted, but rather dynamically linking to incompatible versions of shared libraries. Think of Python 2.6 vs. Python 3

Comment: @sehe, `SIGILL` is sent when a process attempts to execute an instruction with an illegal opcode (hence `ILL`), so physical corruption of a binary (or of any linked library) appears to be more plausible. I'd check the file system(s) and their underlying storage, Jeff.

Comment: @kostix Define "plausible" [sic]. I've had this happen on occasion when running in chroots, so binaries aren't always intended for the proper arch/kernel version. Anyways, I hope you don't actually run an disk/filesystem that makes actual corruption likely :/